# How do I add a feature to double the size of the circles for every mouse click?

Tags: java, geometry, processing, draw

I have the following code setup in processing which creates a circle with different colours for every time I click the mouse. I want to know how to add the feature of the radius of the circle also doubling every time the mouse click creates a new circle.

```java
int value = 0;
int r = 30;

void setup(){
    size(600, 600);
}

void draw(){
    if(mousePressed){
        fill(value, 100, 100);
        ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, r, r);
    }
}

void mousePressed(){
    value = (int) random (1, 255);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just double the `radius` variable in the `mousePressed` function:

```
int value = 0;
int r = 30;

void setup(){
    size(600, 600);
}

void draw(){
    if(mousePressed){
        fill(value, 100, 100);
        ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, r, r);
    }
}

void mousePressed(){
    value = (int) random (1, 255);
    r = r * 2;                       // <------
}
```